# Delphi Android TLocationSensor

Tags: android, delphi

Using Delphi 10.3.

I wrote an android app of notifications based on the geolocalized position.

I have this problem: when I send the app in the background (I verified that it remains running, even with the back button, where I specified not to close it but to send it in the background), TLocationSensor stop tracking the position.

Is there any way around this? or do I have to use a service associated with the app?

But however, with an associated service, it is solved, putting TLocationSensor in the service associated?

Can you still find a quick fix for the background app? (I specify that for the moment I don't care that the app can be closed at any time by android)

Comment: The answer is mostly 'No'. Up until Android 9, you could keep a Foreground (note) Service alive by using a WakeLock, but since Android 10, a JobScheduler is required, but which Embarcadero doesn't yet support.

Comment: But so is there no way now with delphi to keep tracking the position with the position sensor even when the app is in the background? or when the service associated with the app is running?

Comment: A service is your best option.

Comment: You need to use a service. There's an example [here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Playground/tree/main/Demos/Location), however it uses a foreground service, which users might find "intrusive". I have the basics of a solution that uses a JobIntentService [here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Playground/tree/main/Demos/Location), however it has [issues](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Playground/issues/1)